# Use ".npmrc" prefix locally (current project)

Tags: npm, .npmrc

Is it possible to set a **local** destination folder for node_modules in a specific project with an **npmrc** file? (not globally)

I tried to use the syntax "prefix=modules" but modified only the global directory.